# How to Convert all strings in List<string> to lower case using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, foreach

I saw a code snippet yesterday in one of the responses here on StackOverflow that intrigued me. It was something like this:

```
 List<string> myList = new List<string> {"aBc", "HELLO", "GoodBye"};

 myList.ForEach(d=>d.ToLower());
```

I was hoping I could use it to convert all items in myList to lowercase. However, it doesn't happen... after running this, the casing in myList is unchanged.

So my question is whether there IS a way, using LINQ and Lambda expressions to easily iterate through and modify the contents of a list in a manner similar to this.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Easiest approach:

```
myList = myList.ConvertAll(d => d.ToLower());
```

Not too much different than your example code. `ForEach` loops the original list whereas `ConvertAll` creates a new one which you need to reassign.

Comment: @leppie: True, it's not - good catch. In this case, worrying about whether it is an instance method or an extension method may be a bit pedantic, but it is definitely accurate. :)

Comment: And string is immutable :P

Answer (score 57):

That's because ToLower **returns** a lowercase string rather than converting the original string.  So you'd want something like this:

```
List<string> lowerCase = myList.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this approach better than the accepted answer because you can use this with any IEnumerable<string>, not just List<string>.

Comment: This solution also works in .NET Core, ConvertAll doesn't exist in .NET Core.

Answer (score 5):

`ForEach` uses `Action<T>`, which means that you could affect `x` if it were not immutable.  Since `x` is a `string`, it is immutable, so nothing you do to it in the lambda will change its properties.  Kyralessa's solution is your best option unless you want to implement your own extension method that allows you to return a replacement value.

Comment: Please do more research if you are not sure... remember something?

Comment: Error is human, the link I provided had 3.5 in bold and 2.0 in normal, I haven't see it. I have deleted my post... a simple comment from you would have been enough. You want to downvote for no reason, than now assume.

Comment: Although I am writing this almost a year later, and although I am not Daok, I will tell you why your answer is "wrong" - you said "Kyralessa's solution is your best option" when it isn't - my solution is cleaner and clearer.

Answer (score 4):

```
[TestMethod]
public void LinqStringTest()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string> { "aBc", "HELLO", "GoodBye" };
    myList = (from s in myList select s.ToLower()).ToList();
    Assert.AreEqual(myList[0], "abc");
    Assert.AreEqual(myList[1], "hello");
    Assert.AreEqual(myList[2], "goodbye");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var _reps = new List(); // with variant data

_reps.ConvertAll<string>(new Converter<string,string>(delegate(string str){str = str.ToLower(); return str;})).Contains("invisible"))
```